# Extracting one group of data from a JSON reponse in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have an API call that passes this list of 'users' [USER API](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users).

I am trying to retrieve and display only one user at a time.

I currently have this;

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        contacts: []

      }
      componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ contacts: data })
        })
        .catch(console.log)
      }render() {
      const con = this.state.contacts

    return (

<div classname="header">
    <div classname="row">
        <div classname="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
        {con.map((contact) => (
            <h5 class="name">Hello - {contact.name}</h5>
        ))}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
    );
  }
}
   ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,

    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Which passing the name of every contact when I just want the one.
I am new and currently learning - I am guessing I need to be using keys here but after following a few tutorials I'm still at a loss?

Many Thanks.

Comment: `data` is an array. In order to show only one, you should specify the index of the entity you want zero based. For example, in order to show the first, you should `this.setState({ contact: data[0] })` and then, in render replace the whole map in block with `<h5 class="name">Hello - {contact.name}</h5>`

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and works as stated - Thank you @MoshFeu. 
The above is obviously only extracting one portion of the data from the array into the state.
Do I have to then make another API call to access the others? For example, lets say I wanted to now display two of the contacts from that list instead of just the one?

Comment: It depends on your needs. You can fetch all of the records, store them in memory (just a variable) and query it over and over. Or, you can fetch (if the api allows it) only few. It usually what apps do with pagination.